# Fill select dropdown with JSON file data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

I have `JSON` file created by myself, and want to fill `select>option` with this data. But I'm getting `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///C:/.../policy_app_policytype.json. (Reason: CORS request not http).` How can I fix it ? Here are my codes:

`index.html`:

```
<div id="insurance-type">
  <select name="insurance-type-select" id="insurance-type-select">
    <option></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

`script.js`:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var url = "policy_app_policytype.json";
            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('#insurance-type-select').append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.display_name + '</option>');
                });
            });
        });
```

`json`:

```
[
    {
        "description": "Avtonəqliyyat vasitəsi sahiblərinin mülki məsuliyyətinin icbari sığortası şəhadətnaməsi",
        "display_name": "AVSMMİS",
        "id": 1,
        "insurance_type": 1,
        "is_other": 0,
        "policy_type_id": 1,
        "prefix": null,
        "reasons_id": null,
        "status": null,
        "temp_prefix": null
    },
    {
        "description": "Daşınmaz əmlakın icbari sığortası şəhadətnaməsi",
        "display_name": "DƏİS",
        "id": 2,
        "insurance_type": 1,
        "is_other": 0,
        "policy_type_id": 2,
        "prefix": null,
        "reasons_id": null,
        "status": null,
        "temp_prefix": null
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

CORS requests may only use the HTTPS URL scheme, but the URL specified by the request is of a different type. This often occurs if the URL specifies a local file, using a `file:///` URL.

To fix this problem, simply make sure you use HTTPS URLs when issuing requests involving CORS, such as XMLHttpRequest, Fetch APIs, Web Fonts (@font-face), and WebGL textures, and XSL stylesheets.

But if you really want to read a local file use some strategies like in [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles//):